# PHP loop by step

Tags: php

I need help with PHP, I tried loops but that ain't exactly what I need, at least, I can't make it work as I need it.

The idea is to get a given number of `$step = 12;` and a `$value_to_check = 30;` and get a result `$final`, in this case should be: `2`. The result, must be calculated automatically adding `1` every step, the first step is always `0`.

Some examples:

> If `$value_to_check` is between 0 and 11 (step is 12), the `$final` is `0`
>
> If `$value_to_check` is between 12 and 23 (step is 24), the `$final` is `1`
>
> If `$value_to_check` is between 24 and 35 (step is 36), the `$final` is `2`
>
> And so on until the `$value_to_check` matches inside a `$step`

This is one of the loops I tried, but is not working as I need it to be.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 1000; $i++) {   
  if ($i % 12 === 0) {
      $final = 1;
  } else if ($i % 24 === 0) {
      $final = 2;
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me with this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does it mean *"is not working as I need it to be."*? Are you just looking to find out how many times 12 goes into some number? i.e. [`intdiv()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$final` is the "page" your `$value_to_check` is in based on the `$value`

```
echo floor($value_to_check / $step);
```

No need for loops

Answer (score 2):

You can just use divison and integer rounding.

```
0/12 = (int)0 => 0
1/12 = (int)1/12 => 0
12/12 = (int)12/12 => 1
...
```

so the code would look like

```
$finals = [];
for ($i = 0; $i <= 1000; $i++) {   
  $finals[] = intdiv($i, 12);
}

print_r($finals);
```

Edit: Used suggested function `intdiv`, but requires `php7.x`

Comment: It's probably better to use [`intdiv()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.intdiv.php), though.